# why eval() is not evaluating two values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, eval, calculator

i am new to coding, attended few boot-camps & now trying to make a calculator in javascript.
Problem arises when i try to evaluate 2 values when = is clicked. Please sensei guide me.
i tried few work around but they didn't worked, watched few youtube videos but felt like i am copy pasting some one else code in my project so to improve i need to do stuff on my own or at least know where the problem is.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
var result = document.getElementById('screen')


function number() {
  for (num of buttons) {
    num.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      buttonText = e.target.innerText
      console.log(buttonText)
      result.value += buttonText

      if (buttonText === '=') {
        result.value = eval('result.value')

      } else if (buttonText === 'x') {
        buttonText = '*'

      } else if (buttonText === 'C') {
        result.value = ''

      }

    })

  }
}
number()
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

input:focus {
  border: none;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  width: 3.38rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d4c2c2;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #d4c2c2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c77dc29510.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" id="screen" />

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color: aliceblue;"><button> <i class="fas fa-backspace"</i> </button></td>
        <td><button>C</button></td>
        <td><button>%</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>7</button></td>
        <td><button>8</button></td>
        <td><button>9</button></td>
        <td><button>x</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>4</button></td>
        <td><button>5</button></td>
        <td><button>6</button></td>
        <td><button>-</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>1</button></td>
        <td><button>2</button></td>
        <td><button>3</button></td>
        <td><button>+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <td><button>0</button></td>
      <td><button>.</button></td>
      <td><button>/</button></td>
      <td><button>=</button></td>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: May be you meant `eval(result.value)` to evaluate the contents of the string!

Comment: Why would you do this ? This would just set the property to what it is already.

Comment: You're trying to evaluate an actual string: `result.value = eval('result.value')`. You need to remove thew quotes around the variable. (also use an editor with code highlighting and always check how the editor colors the parts of your code)

Comment: Your code is evaluating `'result.value'`, which then returns the value of `result` element. As phuzi said, you need to eval the string in the value, i.e. `result.value`,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments: You're evaluating the string `'result.value'`, instead of the contents of `result.value`.

As well as that, you're adding the symbol `=` to the "screen", which makes the evaluation fail. I made a fix below.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
var result = document.getElementById('screen')


function number() {
  for (num of buttons) {
    num.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      buttonText = e.target.innerText
      console.log(buttonText)

      if (buttonText === '=') {
        result.value = eval(result.value)
      } else if (buttonText === 'x') {
        result.value = '*'
      } else if (buttonText === 'C') {
        result.value = ''
      } else { // I added this part, and removed it from above the ifs
        result.value += buttonText
      }

    })

  }
}
number()
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'sans-serif', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding: .2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

input:focus {
  border: none;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

button {
  width: 3.38rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d4c2c2;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #d4c2c2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c77dc29510.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <input type="text" value="" id="screen" />

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color: aliceblue;"><button> <i class="fas fa-backspace"</i> </button></td>
        <td><button>C</button></td>
        <td><button>%</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>7</button></td>
        <td><button>8</button></td>
        <td><button>9</button></td>
        <td><button>x</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>4</button></td>
        <td><button>5</button></td>
        <td><button>6</button></td>
        <td><button>-</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>1</button></td>
        <td><button>2</button></td>
        <td><button>3</button></td>
        <td><button>+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <td><button>0</button></td>
      <td><button>.</button></td>
      <td><button>/</button></td>
      <td><button>=</button></td>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="calculator.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: This is basically a typo question and even if you disagree, there's a more than 100% chance that this is a duplicate. Please check for these first before posting an answer.

Comment: @ChrisG I don't see the problem in helping the man get his answer, even if there exists a duplicate. I won't mind anyone marking this question as duplicate, but he needed a helping hand.

Comment: Marking it as dupe a) answers the question b) removes clutter from the site. It's why the possibility to mark as dupe exists in the first place. This website is not primarily about helping individuals with their coding issues, it's primarily about creating an exhaustive collection of common programming problems and their solutions.